# Como indicar el index de inicio de un select que se crea desde un javascript para un calendario

Tags: javascript, html, css

espero me puedan ayudar :D, estoy trabajando con HTML, JS y CSS.
Tengo que implementar un calendario con javascript, porque me solicitan no incluir plugins ni tampoco Jquery ya que debe funcionar en IE 5

Desde JavaScript:
esta es la parte en la que se pinta el encabezado donde se encuentra el select de Mes y Año del calendario junto con los títulos de los días de la semana

```
    var a_class, s_html = '<table id="' + s_pfx + 'Controls"><tbody><tr>'
        + '<td align="center" id="' + s_pfx + 'PrevMonth"' + f_tcalRelDate(d_date, -1) + ' title="' + A_TCALCONF.prevmonth + '"><</td><th>'
        + '<select id="idMes"><option value="0">Enero</option><option value="1">Febrero</option><option value="2">Marzo</option><option value="3">Abril</option><option value="4">Mayo</option><option value="5">Junio</option><option value="6">Julio</option><option value="7">Agosto</option><option value="8">Septiembre</option><option value="9">Octubre</option><option value="10">Noviembre</option><option value="11">Diciembre</option></select><th>'
        //+ A_TCALCONF.months[d_date.getMonth()] -> esto esta comentado porque en el calendario se muestra el Mes estático como un label y requiero que sea un select desplegable
        + '<select id="anio" name="Anio"><option value=2010>2010</option><option value=2011>2011</option><option value=2012>2012</option><option value=2013>2013</option><option value=2014>2014</option><option value=2015>2015</option><option value=2016>2016</option><option value=2017>2017</option><option value=2018>2018</option><option value=2019>2019</option><option value=2020>2020</option><option value=2021>2021</option><option value=2022>2022</option><option value=2023>2023</option><option value=2024>2024</option><option value=2025>2025</option><option value=2026>2026</option><option value=2027>2027</option><option value=2028>2028</option><option value=2029>2029</option><option value=2030>2030</option><option value=2031>2031</option><option value=2032>2032</option><option value=2033>2033</option><option value=2034>2034</option><option value=2035>2035</option><option value=2036>2036</option><option value=2037>2037</option><option value=2038>2038</option><option value=2039>2039</option><option value=2040>2040</option><option value=2041>2041</option><option value=2042>2042</option><option value=2043>2043</option><option value=2044>2044</option><option value=2045>2045</option><option value=2046>2046</option><option value=2047>2047</option><option value=2048>2048</option><option value=2049>2049</option><option value=2050>2050</option></select><th>'
        //+ d_date.getFullYear() -> esto esta comentado porque en el calendario se muestra el año estático como un label y requiero que sea un select desplegable
        + '</th><td align="center" id="' + s_pfx + 'NextMonth"' + f_tcalRelDate(d_date, 1) + ' title="' + A_TCALCONF.nextmonth + '">></td>'
        + '</tr></tbody></table><table id="' + s_pfx + 'Grid"><tbody><tr>';

    // imprimir títulos de días de semana
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        s_html += '<th>' + A_TCALCONF.weekdays[(A_TCALCONF.weekstart + i) % 7] + '</th>';
    s_html += '</tr>' ;
```

para indicar el index del select puse la siguiente función que se llama partir del body onload="llenar()" desde HTML

```
function llenar(){
    d_date = new Date();
    var indexMes = d_date.getMonth();
    document.getElementById("idMes").selectedIndex = indexMes;
    var indexYear = d_date.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("idYear").selectedIndex = indexYear;
}
```

El error que me da es:
"No se puede establecer la propiedad 'selectedIndex' de referencia nula o sin definir", sin importar que ya le estoy pasando el Id del select correspondiente para llenar

Comment: En la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) tienes ejemplos de coml usarlo

Comment: De hecho si ya lo revise, duplique un ejemplo parecido, desde html mi select si lo reconoce, el problema esta en que se crea desde JavaScript y no me lo reconoce

Comment: Algún error en la consola?

Comment: este: No se puede establecer la propiedad 'selectedIndex'

Comment: De dónde viene s_pfx? Es el error que me está dando a mi ahora